# Passing multiple parameters into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, filter

I am trying to pass two parameters into this function :

```
onclick="FWP.reset()"
```

It works if I pass I single facet choice in there as :

```
onclick="FWP.reset('day')"
```

But I cannot get it to take multiple parameters such as :

```
 onclick="FWP.reset('day', 'time')"
```

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: well does it support multiple arguments? I have no clue what FWP.....

Comment: I guess maybe not, my coding isn't strong enough to know where to find out

Comment: At the javascript level, you sure can have more then 1 argument.  http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch15.html.  As mentionned by @epascarello, does the function know what do to with the args?

Comment: FWP is from FacetWP a filtering plugin for wordpress

Comment: Well from the very limited documentation here: https://facetwp.com/documentation/js-variables/ I say no, the second argument is the option selected for the first one. So make two calls.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look. How do I make two calls with a single onclick function?

Comment: Don't know if it makes sense: `onclick="FWP.reset('day'); FWP.reset('time')"`

Comment: I gave that one a go and it will only call the first function, not the second